# What's the benefit of allowing python files to import themselves

Tags: python

I can't tell you how many times I've been bitten by accidentally naming my file like something I'm trying to import, resulting in python importing the file. This example should show what I'm talking about (my first example didn't work) if / is in PYTHONPATH:

```
/foo
  __init__.py
/test
  foo.py
```

`__init__.py`

```
def do_thingy():
    print "Swosh!"
```

`foo.py`

```
from foo import * # Whops! Self include. Happy debugging.

do_thingy() # Not imported. You fail.
```

[django](/questions/tagged/django) seem to silently fail when applications, modules, plugins have this error, and the go to method of debugging that (I've been told) is to go to shell and import everything until you find the thing that's broken.

Is there any actual use for recursive imports?

Comment: I'm confused by your example. I tried out your code by laying out the files like you specified, defining `do_thingy` in foo/bar.py, and copying the code for foo.py. When I ran foo.py, `do_thingy()` executed exactly as intended. I'm running Python 2.6.6. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: +1 for "Happy debugging" comment.

Comment: @eksortso - No you are right, it was working. I was trying to reduce it to the simplest case and accidentally made it work. The updated example should break, but requires PYTHONPATH to be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python namespaces require each name to be distinct. Any time you import a module it is always imported into the global namespace. On the front end, these are just simple assignments. If you import something that collides with a name that is already there, it will silently replace the reference to which the name is assigned.

You wouldn't want Python to "remind" you every time you re-assigned a variable, so why would you want it to do the same for a module import?

Case in point:

```
import foo as bar
bar = None
```

Guess what?  You just replaced the module object that was assigned to `bar` with the value `None`.

And finally, to answer your question:  Recursive imports are never a good idea because they are confusing at best and dangerous at worst.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a use for importing yourself.  But there also isn't a use for having two things that could be imported by the same name, so there's no point in detecting the case you've given and treating it specially.

Comment: Sometimes the two things are in different directories, so it's not as blatantly obvious as in the case I gave. I'm just curious if there's a reason why python doesn't explode with an error telling me I'm stupid. I'd prefer that instead of - as seem to be the case when this happens while I'm doing things with Django - it silently failing. So I would argue there's at least a tiny point.